# delete bulk from mysql php not working

Tags: php, mysql

I need to delete bulk from mysql php with pdo object

I have array like this

```
 $emails= array();
  foreach ($items_emails as $datav) {

 $emails[] = $datav[5];
}
```

and then I try to use pdo object to delete from mysql with array parameter

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM ".$data_table." WHERE email_address = :email_address";   
     $stmt = $db_datas->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute(array(':email_address' => $emails));
```

I get this error

Array to string conversion  exactly in this statement

```
 $stmt->execute(array(':email_address' => $emails));
```

Comment: `$emails` is an array, not a string. Iterate over `$emails` and delete each `email` I'd guess.

Comment: this take a long time to delete eache email

Comment: You could do it in one with an `in` and put a placeholder for each `address` in the array.

Answer (score 1):

The `"DELETE FROM x WHERE y = z"` syntax only accepts a single value for comparison, that is why passing an array fails. You can loop over your array of values and delete the entries individually like so:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM ".$data_table." WHERE email_address = :email_address";   
$stmt = $db_datas->prepare($sql);

foreach ($emails as $email) {
    $stmt->execute(array(':email_address' => $email)); 
}
```

or alternatively, use [WHERE x IN (list)](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/where-in) to turn it into a single query:

```
$numberOfPlaceholders = count($emails);
$placeholdersArray = str_split(str_repeat('?', $numberOfPlaceholders));
$placeholders = implode(',', $placeholdersArray);
$sql = "DELETE FROM $data_table WHERE email_address IN ($placeholders)";
$stmt = $db_datas->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($emails);
```

You need to create a separate placeholder for every element in the list to be able to pass an array as pointed out in the comments!

Comment: Your `implode` method won't work. None of the `emails` will match.

Comment: Care to elaborate? It's used with `IN` not `=` in that example. Or I'm just really tired and can't see it.

Comment: It's a binding though so it would come out as `WHERE email_address IN ('chris@gmail.com, chris@yahoo.com')` <-- that'd be 1 string with multiple emails. e.g. `chris@gmail.com` nor `chris@yahoo.com` would be deleted. You can use the `in` just need to count the number for values in `$emails`, insert that many placeholders, then bind the array.

Comment: Ah you're right, it doesn't merge the SQL and input strings. I'll just correct that and go to sleep then. :D

Comment: NOt work this is var_dump()  for $emails 
array(3) { [0]=> string(24) "sten39@gmail.com" [1]=> string(20) "jeffs@gmail.com" [2]=> string(16) "whdf65uc@gmail.com" [3]=> NULL }

Comment: Glad that resolved it, and thanks @chris85 for pointing out my mistake!